# I want my ASP.NET MVC project to be a subsite on my server. How do I do this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I built my project and I tried it out by going to

```
mysite.com/myControllerName1/Index,
mysite.com/myControllerName2/Index,
.
.
.
```

but in fact I want the site to be in

```
mysite.com/mySubfolder
```

, a subfolder I've already created, so that I go to the

```
mysite.com/mySubfolder/myControllerName1/Index
mysite.com/mySubfolder/myControllerName2/Index
.
.
.
```

I assumed it would be as simple as changing

```
routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

to

```
routes.MapRoute(
      name: "Default",
      url: "mySubfolder/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

but after I built the project I was getting a 403 error for `mysite.com/mySubfolder` and a 404 error for `mysite.com/mySubfolder/myControllerName1/Index`, `mysite.com/mySubfolder/myControllerName2/Index`, etc.

What should I really be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an MVC Area, and call the area mySubfolder

Answer (score 2):

In IIS Manager, right-click on `mySubFolder` and select "Convert to Application".

Once you've done that, your original routes should work as expected.

The following article has more details:
[Understanding Sites, Applications, and Virtual Directories on IIS 7](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis)